# Windows Phone Application Update Process

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm A Windows Phone Developer

I Have A Published App Which Has Sqlite Database, I Wanna Update App To A Newer Version, Changes Are Just Effected Desing And App Emprovement.

I Want To Know If I Upload Updated Package Into WinPhone Store And After Users Updated Application, Database Will Be Effected Or Not? I Mean Does Application Data In The Database Will Be Remove Or Not?

Comment: is your database in isolated storage? unrelated: english uses mostly lowercase for the first letter in a word

Comment: Y u capitalize every word?!

Comment: Yeah, Its In Isolated Storage @thumbmunkeys

Answer (score 0):

As your database is in isolated storage, it will be unaffected by the update. This means the same data will be in it after the update.

If your database schema changed, then your app has to handle the transfer of the old schema to the new schema.